# Error response from daemon: Get "https://public.ecr.aws/v2/": denied: Not Authorized

Tags: amazon-ecr

I am trying to upload to AWS a docker container and i have the following up-to-date-versions:

```
➜  ~ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.6
aws cli:
aws-cli/2.13.17 Python/3.11.5 Linux/5.15.0-83-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
```

When i try the first command in the push commands for my public repo:

```
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/m5c0a2h3
```

i get:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://public.ecr.aws/v2/": denied: Not Authorized
```

Comment: Are you the owner of the public ECR repository? If so, you could check the IAM policies associated to your repo and the user you are using to the login

Comment: @Zorrero I am root user.

Comment: I found this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/getting-started-cli.html maybe it can help with your problem

Comment: @Zorrero it does not: Error daemon response: Timeout exceeded.

Comment: Can you try using `public.ecr.aws` or `public.ecr.aws/your_registry_alias/your_repository_name:image_tag`?